# Django save auto-generated form from DB

Tags: django, django-forms, autosave

I have Course's model and the course consist of several file (stored only link to file, file not uploaded to the server). Number of files is unknown, user can add new links to file using JS. And this links can be edited in the form:

I receive and add new course links in the following way:

```
links  = request.POST.getlist('course-dl-links') 

for link in links:
    CourseFile.objects.create(
        link   = link,
        course = course
    )
```

And can dynamically generate the edit form:

```
class CourseForm(forms.Form):
    # fields...

    def __init__(self, data = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CourseForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
        files = CourseFile.objects.filter(course__id=data.course_id).all()

        for course_file in files:
            self.fields['course-dl-links-%d' % (course_file.id, )] = forms.CharField(initial=course_file.path)
```

But to save the form in this form is difficult.
How to do it in the Django way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra model:

```
class CourseLink(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=255)

# Add a course link
CourseLink.objects.create(course=course, link='http://www.google.nl')

# Add another course link
CourseLink.objects.create(course=course, link='http://www.stackoverflow.com')
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm badly asked the question. There are no problems with storing links, there is the problem with how to get auto-generated fields `fields['course-dl-links-%d' % (course_file.id, )]` and ids in db table, that should be updated. Maybe there are better way to do it?